# parsing and combining csv files into another csv file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a list of `csv` files which are in the same directory and trying to combine these 2 files and make one new `csv` file which has the contents of both input files. here is an example of 2 input files:

small_example1.csv

```
    CodeClass,Name,Accession,Count
    Endogenous,CCNO,NM_021147.4,18
    Endogenous,MYC,NM_002467.3,1114
    Endogenous,CD79A,NM_001783.3,178
    Endogenous,FSTL3,NM_005860.2,529
```

small_example2.csv

```
    CodeClass,Name,Accession,Count
    Endogenous,CCNO,NM_021147.4,196
    Endogenous,MYC,NM_002467.3,962
    Endogenous,CD79A,NM_001783.3,390
    Endogenous,FSTL3,NM_005860.2,67
```

and here is the expected output file (`result.csv`):

```
    Probe_Name,Accession,Class_Name,small_example1,small_example2
    CCNO,NM_021147.4,Endogenous,18,196
    MYC,NM_002467.3,Endogenous,1114,962
    CD79A,NM_001783.3,Endogenous,178,390
    FSTL3,NM_005860.2,Endogenous,529,67
```

to do so, I made this function in python3:

```
    import pandas as pd
    filenames = ['small_example1.csv', 'small_example2.csv']
    path = '/home/Joy'
    def convert(filenames):
        for file in filenames:
            df1 = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=26, skipfooter=5, sep=',')
            df = df1.merge(df2, on=['CodeClass', 'Name', 'Accession'])
            df = df.rename(columns={'Name': 'Probe_Name',
                            'CodeClass': 'Class_Name',
                             file: file})
            df.to_csv('result.csv')
```

the results look like this and the last 2 columns are not like expected (both `headers` and `numbers`).

```
        Class_Name  Probe_Name  Accession   Count_x Count_y
    0   Endogenous  CCNO    NM_021147.4 18  18
    1   Endogenous  MYC NM_002467.3 1114    1114
    2   Endogenous  CD79A   NM_001783.3 178 178
    3   Endogenous  FSTL3   NM_005860.2 529 529
```

do you know how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I propose you to first load your dataframes and store them in a list, and then merge them all together (with an inner or outer join, according to your needs) :

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

filenames = ['small_example1.csv', 'small_example2.csv']
path = '/home/Joy'

def convert(filenames):
    dataframes = []

    # load all the dataframes in a list (dataframes)
    for filename in filenames:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=26, skipfooter=5, sep=',')
        df = df.rename(columns={'Count': filename})
        dataframes.append(df)

    # merge the dataframes
    df_merged = reduce(lambda x,y: pd.merge(x,y, on=['CodeClass', 'Name', 'Accession'], how='outer'), dataframes)

    # rename the columns as you want and export the result
    df_merged = df_merged.rename(columns={'Name': 'Probe_Name', 'CodeClass': 'Class_Name'})
    df_merged.to_csv('result.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here, the headers and the values.

If you get twice the same value, you have read twice the same file. You should rename the `Count` column at load time and merge the dataframes into a final one:

```
import pandas as pd
filenames = ['small_example1.csv', 'small_example2.csv']
path = '/home/Joy'
def convert(filenames):
    df = None               # initialize the merged dataframe to None
    for file in d:
        # load a new dataframe and rename its Count columns
        df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(d[file])).rename(columns={'Count': file})
        # merge it into df
        if df is None:
            df = df1
        else:
            df = df.merge(df1, on=['CodeClass', 'Name', 'Accession'])
    # rename and reindex the columns
    result = df.rename(columns={'Name': 'Probe_Name', 'CodeClass': 'Class_Name'}
                       ).reindex(['Probe_Name','Accession','Class_Name']+filenames,
                                 axis=1)
    result.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```